# Clean Architecture UseCase with Progress[No RxJava]

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, clean-architecture

I have a problem trying to figure out the best way to implement a UseCase with a progress. I have seen the examples like:

Google I/O Android App
https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/shared/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/shared/domain/UseCase.kt

What I don't like there is the following:

- You are receive  to recieve the result in the UI and make a lot of decisions there.
- **No progress**

And something that I see as an upgrade to the above is:

Android Architecture Blueprints

https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/usecases/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/domain/ActivateTasksUseCase.kt

They are using Coroutines and now the result is in the ViewModel and it is much better. But again: **No progress**

My problem here is that everybody is using RxJava, because everyone else is using it. I see that a lot of people think that is something "that executes tasks in the background". But it is too much for me. I don't need it.

I've seen some examples with Coroutines channels, but they are really really ugly.

So recently I have stumbled on this article by Roman Elizarov:

https://medium.com/@elizarov/callbacks-and-kotlin-flows-2b53aa2525cf

I did something like this:

```
class ProduceValueWithProgressUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val executor: Executor
) {

    operator fun invoke(): Flow<Result<Int, Int>> {
        return callbackFlow {
            val callback = object : CallbackProgress {
                override fun onProgress(result: Int) {
                    offer(Result.Loading(result))
                }

                override fun onSuccess(result: Int) {
                    offer(Result.Success(result))
                    close()
                }

                override fun onError(e: Exception) {
                    offer(Result.Error(e))
                    close()
                }

            }

            val producer = ValueWithProgressProducer(callback)
            executor.execute(producer)
            awaitClose {}
        }
    }

}
```

The idea is that this thing "producer" is using a callback to propagate the data like most of the "old" APIs. So I want to propagate the code via a flow to the ViewModel and not to put callbacks there. Like this:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
            produceValueWithProgressUseCase().collect {
                when (it) {
                    is Success -> view.showWithProgressResult(it.data)
                    is Loading -> view.updateProgress(it.progress)
                    else -> view.showError()
                }
            }
        }
```

So yes, basically the Flows API will do the work for me. I have created even a small app to test itm where I just generate numbers, and it worked fine. What I did not liked about it was:

- Too much ExperimentalCoroutinesApi annotations had to be in place. For example here(Sorry for the formatting):

  @Suppress("NOTHING_TO_INLINE")
  @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
  public inline fun  callbackFlow(@BuilderInference noinline block: suspend
  ProducerScope.() -> Unit): Flow =
  channelFlow(block)

The above code is part of the file: kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Builders.kt from version: kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.3.2

- At some point I've hit something with a @Preview annotation.(To be honest don't remember where. It was something I've deleted.)
- I tried just a little bit too see how the testing will go, but it is not straightforward. You can see the same in the code from the Blueprinst.
- I also mix the code that executes a task and the task itself. What I mean is the usage of callbackFlow().

So in the end I see something that looks like screaming for change in the next year. So please give your thoughts  on it.

Comment: Can you post some code snippets please? Flow has been stable since Aug 2019. Some of transformation and terminal operators are in experimental and preview I am pretty sure you can achieve what you want without using those.

Comment: @GiorgosNeokleous here you are.

Comment: Indeed `callbackFlow` is not in stable. But you check the stable API, I am pretty sure you can achieve what you are looking for without the `callbackFlow` but instead plain old `Flow`s. Unfortunately I am not on my machine to play around with an example

Comment: I left a rough implementation hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

So I am going to show you an implementation based on what you put in your issue description, feel free to ask more questions and even suggest improvements.

The current implementation is based on the stable version for **Kotlin Coroutines 1.3.2**.

**Interface for Callback**

```
interface CallbackProgress {
    suspend fun onProgress(result: Int)
    suspend fun onSuccess(result: Int)
    suspend fun onError(exception: Exception)
}
```

**Producer**
Iterates and executes some of the callback's method. Trying to mimic yours.

```
class Producer(private val callback: CallbackProgress) {
    suspend fun execute(fail: Boolean) {
        (0 until 10).forEach {
            when {
                it < 9 -> callback.onProgress(it)
                fail -> callback.onError(InterruptedException("blabla"))
                else -> callback.onSuccess(it)
            }
            delay(500)
        }
    }
}
```

**State**

```
sealed class State {
    class Success(val value: Int) : State()
    class Loading(val progress: Int) : State()
    class Error(val exception: Exception) : State()
}
```

**Interactor**
You need to be careful here as the emissions *should be* done within the same coroutine otherwise you will need to use non-stable API such as [channelFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/channel-flow.html).

```
class UseCase {
    operator fun invoke(fail: Boolean) = flow {
        val callback = object : CallbackProgress {
            override suspend fun onSuccess(result: Int) {
                withContext(coroutineContext) { emit(State.Success(result)) }
            }

            override suspend fun onError(exception: Exception) {
                withContext(coroutineContext) { emit(State.Error(exception)) }
            }

            override suspend fun onProgress(result: Int) {
                withContext(coroutineContext) { emit(State.Loading(result)) }
            }
        }

        Producer(callback).execute(fail)
    }
}
```

To test the above I wrote the following which demonstrates both failure and non failure emissions.

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    val useCase = UseCase()
    useCase(true).collect {
        when (it) {
            is State.Loading -> println("State for failure [Loading -> ${it.progress}]")
            is State.Success -> println("State for failure [Success -> ${it.value}]")
            is State.Error -> println("State for failure [Error -> ${it.exception.message}]")
        }
    }
    useCase(false).collect {
        when (it) {
            is State.Loading -> println("State  without failure [Loading -> ${it.progress}]")
            is State.Success -> println("State without failure [Success -> ${it.value}]")
            is State.Error -> println("State without failure [Error -> ${it.exception.message}]")
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
State for failure [Loading -> 1]
State for failure [Loading -> 2]
State for failure [Loading -> 3]
State for failure [Loading -> 4]
State for failure [Loading -> 5]
State for failure [Loading -> 6]
State for failure [Loading -> 7]
State for failure [Loading -> 8]
State for failure [Error -> blabla]

-------------------------------------

State  without failure [Loading -> 0]
State  without failure [Loading -> 1]
State  without failure [Loading -> 2]
State  without failure [Loading -> 3]
State  without failure [Loading -> 4]
State  without failure [Loading -> 5]
State  without failure [Loading -> 6]
State  without failure [Loading -> 7]
State  without failure [Loading -> 8]
State without failure [Success -> 9]
```